# Vue "emit" alternative

Tags: vue.js, events, vue-events

Vue complain when I use "emit" I'm looking for a **same-functioning** alternative

It will be a todo list

Code:

```html
<button @click="$emit('delete-todo-event', todo.id)">Button</button>
```

Warnig in the Browser-Console:

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Extraneous non-emits event listeners deleteTodoEvent) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option. at <ToDos todoEntries= (9) [Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy] onDeleteTodoEvent=fn<bound deleteToDoItem> > at <App>

Comment: It is only a Warnig and no Error
but it bothers because it trashes the console

Comment: Did you try what the warning suggests: "... declare it using the "emits" option"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this because I'm not very familiar with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using Vue 3. The warning tells you that you did not declare your event before using it in your component. Here is an example:

```
export default {
  name: "YourComponent",
  emits: ["deleteTodoEvent"], // <--- this is what the warning in hinting to
  setup(_,{ emit }) {
    ...
  },
};
```

Comment: Should I put this in the same component or the parent component

Comment: In the component which is emitting this event, so i guess in the "same" component.

Comment: How should I trigger the event with the delete-event with the id
Another problem is that I have two events, one with @ click and one with @ blur